# Error : Component [ComponentName] declared `PropTypes` instead of `propTypes`. Did you misspell the property assignment?

Tags: react-native, react-props, react-proptypes, prop

Someone can explain why I get this error when I import PropTypes :

Component CustomBackground declared `PropTypes` instead of `propTypes`. Did you misspell the property assignment?

**CustomBackground.js :**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const CustomBackground=({children})=>(
    <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.imagebackground}>
        {children}
    </ImageBackground>
)

CustomBackground.PropTypes={
    children:PropTypes.element.isRequired,
}

export default CustomBackground;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use camelCase instead of TitleCase when defining propTypes.

Do this:

```
CustomBackground.propTypes = {...}
```

instead of

```
CustomBackground.PropTypes = {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code

```
CustomBackground.propTypes={
    children:PropTypes.element.isRequired,
}
```